# How to find implementation of FragmentManager

Tags: android, fragmentmanager

In my code I am receiving the following error in an edge case:

`android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.getBackStackEntryAt (FragmentManager.java:634)`

I have tried checking out the declaration of `getBackStackEntryAt` but I can only find the `FragmentManager` interface. How can I find the actual implementation so that I can view the source code and determine what is going wrong?

Comment: Share the complete error to better understand your problem

Comment: My question is how to find the source code, not how to debug my error

Comment: Goto grepCode, here is the source link: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.java#FragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt%28int%29

Comment: That just shows an abstract method, I want the implementation of FragmentManager

Comment: Scroll down, you'll get its implementation code.
See here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.java#FragmentManagerImpl

Answer (score 0):

Hold the **ctrl** key and hover mouse pointer on `FragmentManager` and when name turns into blue like links, press left-click on it to view the source code.
It applies to any inbuilt class.

Comment: This won't help, it just takes you to an abstract class, without telling you which classes implement it.